# Modelsim Error: No objects found matching '/test/*'

Tags: verilog, modelsim

I am a newbie to modelsim and Verilog. I designed a DFF(D flip flop module) and a test bench for testing it. But I can't get why modelsim give me this error:

> No objects found matching '/test/*'

test bench code:

```
  // Testbench
  module test;

    reg clk;
    reg reset;
    reg d;
    wire q;
    wire qb;

    // Instantiate design under test
    dff DFF(.clk(clk), .reset(reset),
            .d(d), .q(q), .qb(qb));

    initial begin
      // Dump waves
      $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
      $dumpvars(1);

      $display("Reset flop.");
      clk = 0;
      reset = 1;
      d = 1'bx;
      display;

      $display("Release reset.");
      d = 1;
      reset = 0;
      display;

      $display("Toggle clk.");
      clk = 1;
      display;
    end

    task display;
      #1 $display("d:%0h, q:%0h, qb:%0h",
        d, q, qb);
    endtask
    endmoudle
```

DFF code:

```
// Design
// D flip-flop
module dff (clk, reset,
  d, q, qb);
  input      clk;
  input      reset;
  input      d;
  output     q;
  output     qb;

  reg        q;

  assign qb = ~q;

  always @(posedge clk or posedge reset)
  begin
    if (reset) begin
      // Asynchronous reset when reset goes high
      q <= 1'b0;
    end else begin
      // Assign D to Q on positive clock edge
      q <= d;
    end
  end
endmodule
```

for simulating I first compile both files then simulate the test bench. after this, I go to the wave windows and try to put the test into the wave but at this point I get the error I have mentioned at the first.

Comment: To be honest, this doesn't sound like a programming problem. What command are you giving to Modelsim to cause this error?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question doesn't appear to be about programming.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was with the optimization. I simulate this code with:

> vsim -novopt destination

and everything went fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not on the HDL, you're likely missing the full prefix. Try

```
add wave 'sim:/test/*'
```

Paths passed to the `add wave` command are relative to the unit selected on the Structure (View -> Structure (z)). If in doubt, you can get the absolute path by going to the Structure view, right clicking the testbench and selecting Copy.